# Different language keeps appearing on language bar?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I'm using a Japanese layout keyboard and using English version of Windows 7. I set my input method to *Japanese (Japan) - Japanese* , so that I can have all keys working properly.

I got this weird problem recently. There is always *English (United States) - US* appeared on my language bar. When I check my settings, everything is fine like what I set. Although it doesn't annoy me too much, I want to know if there is a solution for this weird problem?

Here is a photo of my settings:

[image]

Comment: do you connect remotely to this computer (with remote desktop) ?

Comment: I dont. I just recently reinstall Windows 7 on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel > Region & Language > Keyboards & languages > Change keyboards

Put Japanese as your default input language and remove all other entries.

As an extra you can then go back to the region & language section, choose the Administrative tab > Copy Settings > Tick: Welcome screen & system accounts / New user accounts, click ok.

Also, you can hide this bar: Keyboard & Languages > Change keyboards > Language bar > Tick Hidden

Comment: nah there is only Japanese (Japan) - Japanese in the input language properties but there are 2 in the language bar